# How to create a nested list in Eclipse WikiText using Markdown format

Tags: eclipse, markdown, mylyn-wikitext, commonmark

I am using the WikiText plugin in Eclipse to write Markdown documentation of my current project.

Unfortunately, despite the Help pages stating that the Markdown implementation complies with CommonMark, I can't seem to create nested lists such as:

- Handles

  - Alfa
  - Bravo
  - Charlie
- Equipment

  - Alfa: AWP
  - Bravo: BAR
  - Charlie: M24 SWS

The same text and "formatting", ie 4 spaces before nested list items gives me, in the Preview, something like

```
- Handles - Alfa - Bravo - Charlie
- Equipment - Alfa: AWP - Bravo: BAR - Charlie: M24 SWS
```

But 4 spaces before nested items is [reported by CommonMark](http://commonmark.org/help/tutorial/10-nestedLists.html) as correct (meaning that it gives me what I want, ie a sublist).

I have tried adding a blank line before `- Alfa` but it turns the list items into code.

I've tried the **WikiText** > **Generate Markdown** command in the context menu and the generated file has two differences:
- The marker for first-level is turned from my given hyphen into an asterisk.
- The second-level items are prepended with eight whitespace characters.

Still, the Preview shows exactly what I've reported above: nested list items are on the same line as their parent.

How do I create nested lists using that plugin? Or does it not support nested lists?

EDIT: after Jmini's answer, here is a screen capture of what I get. I'm using version 2.7.0.v20151009-1723 on Mars.2. Also, I don't have line numbers although the preference is enabled for all editors.

[image: Screen capture of Markdown source and preview]

EDIT #2: A search on Eclipse Bugzilla revealed [this bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=462086) which seems relevant. Given the difference in version numbers in Jmini's answer, I've updated Mylyn WikiText plugin to the latest weekly build and lo and behold, I now have correctly rendered nested lists in the Preview tab of the WikiText Markdown editor. Conclusion: it was a bug. The thing I can't fathom though is how a release which happened 7 months after the bug has been fixed didn't contain the fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure to understand your problem.

I have tried this source:

```
- Lorem
    - first
    - second
- Ipsum
    - first
    - second
- Dolor
```

Here a screenshot:

[image: List Markdown in Mylyn WikiText]

The HTML output I got with WikiText (Version `2.8.0v20160121-2126`, Eclipse Neon):

```
<body>
    <ul>
        <li>Lorem</li>
        <ul>
            <li>first</li>
            <li>second</li>
        </ul>
        <li>Ipsum</li>
        <ul>
            <li>first</li>
            <li>second</li>
        </ul>
        <li>Dolor</li>
    </ul>
</body>
```